# ng2-charts display multiple pie charts using *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm trying to display multiple pie charts in the same page that are loaded from the same component. So far I've found only ways where you have to "hard code" the charts instead of iterating through all the data and displaying multiple charts [like shown here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-multiple-charts-aor8tt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). I also decided to follow this way of showing the charts, which results in lines of ugly repetitive code:

my .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { SurveyService } from 'src/app/service/survey.service';
import { ChartsModule, Label, monkeyPatchChartJsLegend, monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip, SingleDataSet } from 'ng2-charts';
import { ChartOptions, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { Survey, SurveyDetail } from '../../dto/survey';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-statistics-fit',
  templateUrl: './statistics-fit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./statistics-fit.component.css']
})
export class StatisticsFitComponent implements OnInit {
  
  empty = false;
  goodCt: number = 0;
  badCt: number = 0;
  mediumCt: number = 0;
  excellentCt: number = 0;
  public appName = '';
  public fits: string[] | undefined;
  public pieChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      text: 'Rated Fit',
      display: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'single',
      callbacks: {
        label: this.showPercent
      }
    }
  };
  public pieChartLabels: Label[] = ['Bad', 'Medium', 'Good', 'Excellent'];
  public pieChartData: any = [{data: []}];
  public pieChartType: ChartType = 'pie';
  public pieChartLegend = true;
  public pieChartPlugins: any;
  public pieChartColors: any = [
    { 
    backgroundColor: ['rgba(248,9,7,1)', 'rgba(248, 154, 7, 1)', 'rgba(7, 121, 248, 1)', 'rgba(90, 201, 40, 1)' ,
      'rgba(102,51,153,1)']
    }
  ];

  surveyAnswers: SurveyDetail[] = [];

  // Second chart ===============================================================================
  b1: string[] | undefined;
  public chartOptB1: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      text: "desc1",
      display: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'single',
      callbacks: {
        label: this.showPercent
      }
    }
  };
  answersB1 = ['Ineffective', 'Somewhat Effective', 'Effective', 'Highly Effective', 'Exceptional'];
  public chartLabelsB1: Label[] = this.answersB1
  public chartDataB1: any = [{data: []}];

  // Third Chart ============================================================================
  b2: string[] | undefined;
  public chartOptB2: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      text: "desc2",
      display: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'single',
      callbacks: {
        label: this.showPercent
      }
    }
  };
  answersB2 = ['Irrelevant', 'Somewhat Relevant', 'Relevant', 'Very Relevant', 'Proactive'];
  public chartLabelsB2: Label[] = this.answersB2;
  public chartDataB2: any = [{data: []}];

  // Fourth Chart =============================================================

  b3: string[] | undefined;
  public chartOptB3: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      text: "desc3",
      display: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'single',
      callbacks: {
        label: this.showPercent
      }
    }
  };
  answersB3 = ['Very Complex', 'Complex', 'Reasonable', 'Simple', 'Very Simple'];
  public chartLabelsB3: Label[] = this.answersB3;
  public chartDataB3: any = [{data: []}];

  // Fifth Chart ==============================================================================

  b4: string[] | undefined;
  public chartOptB4: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      text: "desc4",
      display: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'single',
      callbacks: {
        label: this.showPercent
      }
    }
  };
  answersB4 = ['Sporadic', 'Infrequent', 'Frequent', 'Routine', 'Constant'];
  public chartLabelsB4: Label[] = this.answersB4;
  public chartDataB4: any = [{data: []}];

  // 6th Chart =========================================================

  b5: string[] | undefined;
  public chartOptB5: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      text: "desc5",
      display: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'single',
      callbacks: {
        label: this.showPercent
      }
    }
  };
  answersB5 = ['Difficult', 'Operable', 'Usable', 'Intuitive', 'Streamlined'];
  public chartLabelsB5: Label[] = this.answersB5;
  public chartDataB5: any = [{data: []}];
  
  // 7th Chart =========================================================

  b6: string[] | undefined;
  public chartOptB6: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      text: "desc6",
      display: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'single',
      callbacks: {
        label: this.showPercent
      }
    }
  };
  answersB6 = ['Poor', 'Tolerant', 'Sufficient', 'Excellent', 'Exceptional'];
  public chartLabelsB6: Label[] = this.answersB6;
  public chartDataB6: any = [{data: []}];
  

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private service: SurveyService
    ) {
      monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip();
      monkeyPatchChartJsLegend();
     }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getFits();
    this.getAnswers();
    this.route.queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
      this.appName = params.appName;
    }
  );
  }

  getFits(): void {
    const appId = String(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('appId'));
    this.service.getFits(appId).subscribe({
      next: response => {
        this.fits = response;

        if (this.fits.length === 0) {
          this.empty = true;
        }
        
        this.fits.forEach(current => {
          if (current === 'GOOD') {
            this.goodCt++;
          } else if (current === 'MEDIUM') {
            this.mediumCt++;
          } else if (current === 'BAD') {
            this.badCt++;
          } else if (current === 'EXCELLENT') {
            this.excellentCt++;
          }
        });
        this.pieChartData =  [this.badCt, this.mediumCt, this.goodCt, this.excellentCt];
      }
    });
  }

  showPercent(tooltipItem: Chart.ChartTooltipItem, data: Chart.ChartData) {
    var allData = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
    var tooltipLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
    var tooltipData = allData[tooltipItem.index];
    var sum = 0 
    allData.forEach(elem => {
      sum += +elem;
    });
    var percent = Math.round(+tooltipData*100/sum);
    return tooltipLabel + ": " + tooltipData + " (" + percent + "%)";
  }

  getAnswers() {
    const appId = String(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('appId'));
    this.service.getAllAnswers(appId).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.surveyAnswers = response;
        this.makeB1();
        this.makeB2();
        this.makeB3();
        this.makeB4();
        this.makeB5();
      }
    );

  }

  makeB1(): void {
    var ct1 = 0;
    var ct2 = 0;
    var ct3 = 0;
    var ct4 = 0;
    var ct5 = 0;
    this.surveyAnswers.forEach(
      entry => {
        if (entry.b1 === this.answersB1[0]) {
          ct1++;
        } else if (entry.b1 === this.answersB1[1]) {
          ct2++;
        } else if (entry.b1 === this.answersB1[2]) {
          ct3++;
        } else if (entry.b1 === this.answersB1[3]) {
          ct4++;
        } else if (entry.b1 === this.answersB1[4]) {
          ct5++;
        }
      }
    );
    this.chartDataB1 = [ct1, ct2, ct3, ct4, ct5];
  }

  makeB2(): void {
    var ct1 = 0;
    var ct2 = 0;
    var ct3 = 0;
    var ct4 = 0;
    var ct5 = 0;
    this.surveyAnswers.forEach(
      entry => {
        if (entry.b2 === this.answersB2[0]) {
          ct1++;
        } else if (entry.b2 === this.answersB2[1]) {
          ct2++;
        } else if (entry.b2 === this.answersB2[2]) {
          ct3++;
        } else if (entry.b2 === this.answersB2[3]) {
          ct4++;
        } else if (entry.b3 === this.answersB2[4]) {
          ct5++;
        }
      }
    );
    this.chartDataB2 = [ct1, ct2, ct3, ct4, ct5];
  }

  makeB3() {
    var ct1 = 0;
    var ct2 = 0;
    var ct3 = 0;
    var ct4 = 0;
    var ct5 = 0;
    this.surveyAnswers.forEach(
      entry => {
        if (entry.b3 === this.answersB3[0]) {
          ct1++;
        } else if (entry.b3 === this.answersB3[1]) {
          ct2++;
        } else if (entry.b3 === this.answersB3[2]) {
          ct3++;
        } else if (entry.b3 === this.answersB3[3]) {
          ct4++;
        } else if (entry.b3 === this.answersB3[4]) {
          ct5++;
        }
      }
    );
    this.chartDataB3 = [ct1, ct2, ct3, ct4, ct5];
  }

  makeB4() {
    var ct1 = 0;
    var ct2 = 0;
    var ct3 = 0;
    var ct4 = 0;
    var ct5 = 0;
    this.surveyAnswers.forEach(
      entry => {
        if (entry.b4 === this.answersB4[0]) {
          ct1++;
        } else if (entry.b4 === this.answersB4[1]) {
          ct2++;
        } else if (entry.b4 === this.answersB4[2]) {
          ct3++;
        } else if (entry.b4 === this.answersB4[3]) {
          ct4++;
        } else if (entry.b4 === this.answersB4[4]) {
          ct5++;
        }
      }
    );
    this.chartDataB4 = [ct1, ct2, ct3, ct4, ct5];
  }

  makeB5() {
    var ct1 = 0;
    var ct2 = 0;
    var ct3 = 0;
    var ct4 = 0;
    var ct5 = 0;
    this.surveyAnswers.forEach(
      entry => {
        if (entry.b5 === this.answersB5[0]) {
          ct1++;
        } else if (entry.b5 === this.answersB5[1]) {
          ct2++;
        } else if (entry.b5 === this.answersB5[2]) {
          ct3++;
        } else if (entry.b5 === this.answersB5[3]) {
          ct4++;
        } else if (entry.b5 === this.answersB5[4]) {
          ct5++;
        }
      }
    );
    this.chartDataB5 = [ct1, ct2, ct3, ct4, ct5];
  }

  makeB6() {
    var ct1 = 0;
    var ct2 = 0;
    var ct3 = 0;
    var ct4 = 0;
    var ct5 = 0;
    this.surveyAnswers.forEach(
      entry => {
        if (entry.b6 === this.answersB6[0]) {
          ct1++;
        } else if (entry.b6 === this.answersB6[1]) {
          ct2++;
        } else if (entry.b6 === this.answersB6[2]) {
          ct3++;
        } else if (entry.b6 === this.answersB6[3]) {
          ct4++;
        } else if (entry.b6 === this.answersB6[4]) {
          ct5++;
        }
      }
    );
    this.chartDataB6 = [ct1, ct2, ct3, ct4, ct5];
  }

}
```

my .html file:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!empty">
    <h2>Statistics for {{appName}}</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="chart col-md-6">
                <canvas baseChart [data]="pieChartData" [labels]="pieChartLabels" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                    [options]="pieChartOptions" [colors]="pieChartColors" [plugins]="pieChartPlugins">
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="chart col-md-6">
                <canvas baseChart [data]="chartDataB1" [labels]="chartLabelsB1" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                    [options]="chartOptB1" [colors]="pieChartColors" [plugins]="pieChartPlugins">
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="chart col-md-6">
                <canvas baseChart [data]="chartDataB2" [labels]="chartLabelsB2" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                    [options]="chartOptB2" [colors]="pieChartColors" [plugins]="pieChartPlugins">
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="chart col-md-6">
                <canvas baseChart [data]="chartDataB3" [labels]="chartLabelsB3" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                    [options]="chartOptB3" [colors]="pieChartColors" [plugins]="pieChartPlugins">
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="chart col-md-6">
                <canvas baseChart [data]="chartDataB4" [labels]="chartLabelsB4" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                    [options]="chartOptB4" [colors]="pieChartColors" [plugins]="pieChartPlugins">
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="chart col-md-6">
                <canvas baseChart [data]="chartDataB5" [labels]="chartLabelsB5" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                    [options]="chartOptB5" [colors]="pieChartColors" [plugins]="pieChartPlugins">
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="chart col-md-6">
                <canvas baseChart [data]="chartDataB6" [labels]="chartLabelsB6" [chartType]="pieChartType"
                    [options]="chartOptB6" [colors]="pieChartColors" [plugins]="pieChartPlugins">
                </canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>

<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert" *ngIf="empty">
    There are currently no survey evaluations.
</div>
```

I'd also like to note that I haven't found any proper documentation for the library and I'd like to know if the code below can be packed nicely and run through iteratively, instead of me repeating the same logic over and over.